# What does the "bisector angle of vertex for original geometry" mean in the Extract Vertices tool?

Tags: qgis, vertices, angles, complexity

I need to calculate the number of notches in my polygons.
Therefore I need to **know the angles of the vertices** in a set polygons.

I managed to extract a value for the angle by the Extract Vertices tool but cannot make sense of the values I am given. The description of the value is given as "the bisector angle of vertex for original geometry". I tried to search what does this term mean, but to no avail.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just had the same query and only found your unanswered question.  So I drew a line, extracted the vertices and came up with the picture below. The labels are the angles produced by the Extract Vertices tool:[image]

I can't think of the most concise way to say it, but the angles seem to be:
**the average of the bearings of the two line segments connected to the vertex**

Maybe my clumsy wording will provoke a better explanation.

See the vertex at bottom left has an angle of 135 degrees.  The segment leading into the vertex has a bearing of 180 and segment running out of the vertex has a bearing of 90, so if you average those two bearings (or bisect those two angles) you end up with 135.  I found it easier to visualise the bisector if the incoming line segment was relocated to be leading away from the vertex:
[image]

Here's another picture with the angles symbolised (they reminded me of tangents, although I know that's not what they are):[image]

The angle for the first and last vertices are just the bearing of the single segment connected to the vertex.

**Edit:** I guess if the angle is relative to the horizontal you get a different kind of bisector:[image]

Comment: This is a great answer, very intuitive visualization! I wonder why it was not upvoted until now. I already asked myself what kind of value the `angle_at_vertex(geometry,vertex)` expression returns, but with your answer, it becomes clear that it is excatly the same.