# Automatic removal of an extra vertices lying on a straight line or polygonal segment using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vertices

I am looking for a QGIS tool that would allow me to remove extra vertices on a line or segment of a polygon. By extra vertices I mean vertices that lie on a straight line. **The other vertices must remain as they are.**

[image]

Comment: You got an answer that works. Just to add another idea that only deletes vertices in case you have 3 vertices exactly on a single line: you could calculate the azimuth (angle) at each vertex with index n: if the azimuth of the line from (vert. n-1) to (vert n) is equal to the azimuth ( vert. n) to ( vert. n+1), than delete vertex n.

Comment: @Babel Thank you for your suggestion. I found a tool that partially automates this process, but more automation is needed to decide which points to delete: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361633/what-does-the-bisector-angle-of-vertex-for-original-geometry-mean-in-the-extra

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Simplify tool located under the processing toolbox (**works with a tolerance of 0.001 and at CRS in meters**):

[image]

The simplify tool is used to remove vertices based on a threshold (tolerance) value that you can decide after several testing of the suitable value.

From the tool's help:

> This algorithm simplifies the geometries in a line or polygon layer.
> It creates a new layer with the same features as the ones in the input
> layer, but with geometries containing a **lower number of vertices**.

Test polygon as WKT (EPSG:32643 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 43N - Projected):

[image]

```
Polygon ((162775.8826374284690246 6883546.48537494335323572, 163284.30041919217910618 6883546.4853749442845583, 163775.88263742829440162 6883546.48537494521588087, 163775.88263742843992077 6883271.19795066211372614, 163775.88263742858543992 6882987.00823878031224012, 163775.88263742887647822 6882398.4059663126245141, 163539.39316857425728813 6882398.4059663126245141, 163305.26652578474022448 6882398.4059663126245141, 162999.85959377710241824 6882398.4059663126245141, 162775.88263742794515565 6882398.4059663126245141, 162775.88263742814888246 6882857.40979341417551041, 162775.88263742829440162 6883179.11509039346128702, 162775.8826374284690246 6883546.48537494335323572))
```

Simplify result:

[image]

```
Polygon ((162775.8826374284690246 6883546.48537494335323572, 163775.88263742829440162 6883546.48537494521588087, 163775.88263742887647822 6882398.4059663126245141, 162775.88263742794515565 6882398.4059663126245141, 162775.8826374284690246 6883546.48537494335323572))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it will change the other vertices (what is undesirable).

Comment: Probably, yes, since my search for the right tool did not lead to any results.

Comment: @ComradeChe Try using the Simplify tool with a tolerance of 0.001 I tried it on multiple shapes of varying complexity and it seemed to work fine for me. It removed unncecessary vertices that lay on straight lines but did not effecy any other vertices.

Comment: @TeddyTedTed I think it depends on the projection used for the data. If WGS84, `0.001` may work, but if your data is in UTM for example, it will not have an effect since the unit is in meter, so `0.001` m is very low value.

Comment: I tested this on data in a meter unit CRS. The idea is that it is a low threshold so that it only removes points that are on a straight line.

Comment: @TeddyTedTed That is strange because I tested on a polygon with UTM projection, and I used a value of `0.001` and nothing changed.

Comment: @TeddyTedTed  It works for me: https://ibb.co/2sPrzzb

Comment: Please add your test polygon as WKT so others can have a try with the same data. BTW simplify does not move the remaining vertices. It just removes those which are under the tolerance.

Comment: @user30184 Added WTK polygons and pictures.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Simplify tool function is not directly designed to remove extra points lying on the line, I decided to create a custom function that would provide more predictable results of data processing.

This function calculates the azimuths of the directions created from the three points (previous, current and next), if the azimuths coincide - the current vertex will be deleted.

[image]==>
[image]==>
[image]

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import numpy


@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def delete_extra_vertex(geometry, angle_measurement_error, feature, parent):
    """
    Deletes unnecessary vertices that lie on a straight line within line or polygons geometry.

    <h2>Syntax</h2>
    delete_extra_vertex(geometry, angle_measurement_error)

    <h2>Arguments</h2>
    geometry - polygon or line geometry object
    angle_measurement_error - (integer) Number of decimal places to round azimuth.

    <h2>Examples</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>geom_to_wkt(delete_extra_vertex(geom_from_wkt('LineString(0 1, 0 2, 0 3)'), 5)) → 'LineString (0 1, 0 3)'</li>
      <li>geom_to_wkt(delete_extra_vertex(geom_from_wkt('POLYGON((0 0, 0 0.5, 0 1, 1 1, 0 1))'), 5)) → 'Polygon ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 1))'</li>
    </ul>
    """
    new_geometry = qgis.core.QgsGeometry(geometry)  # a deep copy of the initial geometry
    vertex_id_list_to_deletion = []
    vertex_id_list_to_retain = []

    max_vertex_id = len([x for x in geometry.vertices()])

    for current_vertex_num, _ in enumerate(geometry.vertices()):
        previous_vertex_num, next_vertex_num = geometry.adjacentVertices(current_vertex_num)

        previous_vertex = geometry.vertexAt(previous_vertex_num)
        current_vertex = geometry.vertexAt(current_vertex_num)
        next_vertex = geometry.vertexAt(next_vertex_num)

        azimuth_from_previous_vertex_to_current_vertex = numpy.round(previous_vertex.azimuth(current_vertex),
                                                                     angle_measurement_error)
        azimuth_from_current_vertex_to_next_vertex = numpy.round(current_vertex.azimuth(next_vertex),
                                                                 angle_measurement_error)

        if azimuth_from_previous_vertex_to_current_vertex == azimuth_from_current_vertex_to_next_vertex:
            if current_vertex_num in (0, max_vertex_id):  # skip first and last vertex
                pass
            else:
                vertex_id_list_to_deletion.append(current_vertex_num)
        else:
            vertex_id_list_to_retain.append(current_vertex_num)

    vertex_id_list_to_deletion.reverse()
    for vertex_id in vertex_id_list_to_deletion:
        new_geometry.deleteVertex(vertex_id)
    return new_geometry
```

Comment: Interesting!  Will we soon this this as a plugin?

Comment: @StuSmith I am afraid not. =)