# Identifying polygons with arcs using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, circularstring

I have a polygon layer where there may be polygons and circular arcs as in the image.

How can I identify the polygons which have those arcs parts?

[image]

Comment: what does `geom.wkbType()` return?

Comment: It would be really really hard to identify polygons with such "circle-ish" parts computationally. What is your goal? Maybe a different strategy would be possible.

Comment: @ElioDiaz it return 6 -Multipolygon

Comment: @bugmenot123 I have datasets that have many polygons in the field of natural catastrophe.  In the question, I just created similar objects to my original dataset. The goal is to detect that polygon with circular parts and tell users that they are not allowed to use them.  I guess it would be possible in PostGIS.You can explode PostGIS geometries into their basic parts, and an arc will appear as a different geometry type. But I need a QGIS integrated solution. 
The length and point density are what I could think of and try but I do get many false positives with that...

Comment: **Every** polygon has segments which could be circular parts, even if it was only two points of a truly *massive* circle. You need to define your problem in terms of N consecutive vertices which share a common center point when cast as an arc. This is ***extemely*** computationally expensive due to all the trig functions, so you can expect this evaluation to *slam* the CPU on which it is run.

Comment: I'd approach this rather naive and try to determine a threshold of vertices per area (of bounding box) above which the likeliness of an arc within the polygon is high enough.

Comment: @Erik yes, i guess it should be the way to go. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Maybe somethin similar to this approach? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397907/88814

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working on the assumption that in an arc like in the posted screenshot, the distance between vertices will be very similar and the azimuth from one vertex to the next will change at a fairly constant rate, I cobbled together this messy code in the Python Console to test the idea:

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

for f in lyr.selectedFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()

    for p in geom.parts():
        verts = p.vertices()
        p0 = verts.next()
        p1 = verts.next()
        dist = p0.distance(p1)
        az = p0.azimuth(p1)
        dev = 0
        tol = 0.1
        angular_tol_max = 10
        angular_tol_min = 0.01
        in_arc = False
        
        for v in verts:
            d = p1.distance(v)
            a = p1.azimuth(v)
            if((abs(d-dist)/dist) > tol):
                dist = d
                in_arc = False
            else:
                if (angular_tol_min < abs(az-a) < angular_tol_max) and dev != 0:
                    #print ("this might be an arc",((az-a)/dev))
                    if( (-tol) < ((az-a)/dev) > (tol)):     
                        #print ("this realy might be an arc")
                        if in_arc == False:
                            rb = QgsRubberBand(iface.mapCanvas())
                            rb.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
                            rb.setWidth(3)
                            rb.addPoint(QgsPointXY(p0.x(), p0.y()))
                            rb.addPoint(QgsPointXY(p1.x(), p1.y()))
                        rb.addPoint(QgsPointXY(v.x(), v.y()))
                        in_arc = True
                    else:
                        in_arc = False
                else:
                    in_arc = False
            p0 = p1
            p1 = v
            dev = az - a
            az = a
```

It iterates through the vertices comparing the distance and azimuth to the previous vertex, when it detects a segment with a similar length and change in direction as the previous segment it assumes they are part of the arc. The tolerance can be changed by the value of the `tol` variable (current value of 0.1 means up to 10% difference in segment length) and the `angular_tol_max` and `angular_tol_min` currently 10 and 0.01 meaning the azimuth change must be at less than 10 degrees and at at least 0.01 degrees.

It seems to work OK, I expect it would fail where the azimuth of adjacent segments changes from slightly less than 360 to slightly more than zero.

[image]

Comment: It works https://i.imgur.com/MxzaQ1J.png
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should publish this algorithm and write it in a fast implementation. It would get used. Cheers,