# Qgis_Visualize data from attribute table with percentage in curved lines

Tags: qgis

I have an Excel file with sediment data from core and I would like to visualize like curved lines with values 0-5%, 5-10% ..for every sediment column (gravel, sand, silt, clay).

How do I do that?

Comment: See here: dies that help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397907/88814

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would visualize the percentage of sediments on the sea with different colour and labels and for that I thought the curved lines. Specifically, I want to create four maps one for every sediment and how it grows into the sea. I hope to expain you a little more.