# Is the LineString straight?

Tags: qgis, geopandas, shapely, linestring

Is there a way to check whether or not a line string is straight?
there is a `line.is_ring()` method in shapely for rings but I could not find something similar to straight lines. I use shapely and GeoPandas.

My data is the lines for street map. I'm sampling the street as points, I want to somehow detect the straight lines and put less points as samples.
If it is in a form of code I need something efficient and fast.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share some data sample as WKT/WKB?

Comment: Conceptually asked: What is a "straight" line? On Earth's surface, all lines are somehow "curved". So are you looking for projected lines? Do you consider a line as straight if it consists of just two vertices? Then counting the number of of vertices would be the way to go.

Comment: "Straightness" is actually quite subjective. Even a two vertex segment has *some* curvature, and

Comment: @Babel
I added pictures and descriptions to be more clear.

Comment: An idea: connect start- and end- point of the line to a new line and check if this a line (or a very small buffer around it) contains the whole initial line. Easy to do in QGIS without code, e.g. expressions.

Comment: Seems to be similar to this, see here: does that help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397907/88814

Comment: @Vince please read added description and pictures

Comment: @Babel if I calculate the line length and compare it with the distance of the start and end point of a line, setting a threshold, would it be a good idea?
for real-life street sampling how long a threshold could be to consider a line straight?

Comment: @Babel I'm replying to your idea comment
1- add an attribute table
2- create a buffer to a line (start and end point), if contains add 'straight' to attribute table. ow, 'curved'
how can I code this into qgis

Comment: You can simplify the line using Douglas-Peucker simplfication with a small distance tolerance. If the line reduces to just the endpoints it is straight within that distance tolerance.

Comment: @Gaff see the answer added below for the points discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 14):

Maths should always work. You can basically test for the collinearity between the first vector of the line (i.e. composed by the two first points of the line) and all other vectors of the line (i.e. those composed always by the first point and all the other individual points of the line).

If a single one of those vectors breaks the collinearity, your line is not straight.

Code snippet ([shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [numpy](https://numpy.org/) only):

```py
import numpy as np
from shapely import wkt

def check_collinearity(line):
    A = np.array(line.coords)
    a = A[0,:].copy()
    A -= a # align the first point of the line with the origin (0,0)
    check = True
    for i, point in enumerate(A):
        B = np.cross(A[1,:], point) # compute cross product
        if B != 0:
            check = False
            print(f"point {i}: {point+a} breaks collinearity; cross-prod = {B}")
    
    return check
    

line1 = wkt.loads('LINESTRING (1 1, 2 1, 3 1, 4 1, 5 1)') # is collinear
line2 = wkt.loads('LINESTRING (1 1, 2 1, 3 2, 4 1, 5 1)') # is not collinear

check_collinearity(line1)
>: True

check_collinearity(line2)
point 2: [3. 2.] breaks collinearity; cross-prod = 1.0
>: False
```

This is obviously only valid in a Cartesian space, so if your data is not in such a space, you must transform it before using this solution.

Ref: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html

Answer (score 14):

A really simple way is to evaluate the [sinuosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinuosity) for each linestring, using something like this for shapely:

```
def sinuosity(geom):
    assert geom.geom_type == "LineString", geom.geom_type
    length = geom.length
    start_pt = geom.interpolate(0)
    end_pt = geom.interpolate(1, normalized=True)
    straight_dist = start_pt.distance(end_pt)
    if straight_dist == 0.0:
        if length == 0.0:
            return 0.0
        return float("inf")
    return length / straight_dist


from shapely import wkt

line1 = wkt.loads("LINESTRING (1 10, 2 20, 3 30)")  # straight
line2 = wkt.loads("LINESTRING (1 10, 3 20, 3 30)")  # small bend
line3 = wkt.loads("LINESTRING (1 10, 3 20, 3 30, 1 10)")  # closed
line4 = wkt.loads("LINESTRING (1 10, 1 10)")  # zero-length

sinuosity(line1)  # 1.0
sinuosity(line2)  # 1.0048900000681216
sinuosity(line3)  # inf
sinuosity(line4)  # 0.0
```

Straight lines have a sinuosity of 1.0, and values increase for lines that are more sinuous. This function can be easily adapted for GeoPandas or re-written for PostGIS.

Answer (score 11):

A possible approach in QGIS using the [`sinuosity()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#sinuosity) function.

> Returns the sinuosity of a curve, which is the ratio of the curve
> length
> ([`length()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id29))
> to the straight (2D) distance
> ([`straight_distance_2d()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#straight-distance-2d))
> between its endpoints.

As an input only `LineString`s will be accepted.

*An example:*

[image: example]

*Conclusion:* Line with `id=2` is straight.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to somehow detect the straight lines and put less points as
> samples.

Since your question is labeled with PostGIS, what you are trying to achieve above seems to be the "generalization" process in GIS/cartography.

Classic algorithms such as the Douglas-Peucker algorithm is designed to solve such problems: replacing a polyline/curve with a sequence of straight line segments subject to a pre-specified tolerance level. In PostGIS, this algorithm is provided through the [ST_Simplify](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Simplify.html) function.

From the documentation linked above, you can do, e.g.:

```
SELECT geometry ST_Simplify(geom, 0.1);
```

to get straight line approximations of your original polyline subject to an error of 0.1 map unit. Examples of usage can be found in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

#### Find perfectly or almost straight lines

Use QGIS expressions and create a line from the start to the end point of the line. If the initial line is straight, than it is fully within the resulting line (or within a small buffer if you define "straight" within a certain tolerance: see below).

##### Find perfectly straight lines

Use this expression to check this (e.g. creating a new attribute field with Field Calculator):

```
within (
    $geometry, 
    make_line (start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry))
)
```

*Lines labeled with the expression: straight lines=1, not perfectly straight lines=0:*
[image]

##### Variant: Using a certain tolerance:

Use the same expression, but apply a small buffer around the line from start to end point to catch lines that are almost, but not perfectly straight. The larger the buffer size, the greater the tolerence:

```
within (
    $geometry, 
    buffer(
        make_line (start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)),
        0.4)
)
```

*Method using buffers, catching lines that are almost, but not perfectly straight, but sorting out lines clearly not straight (=outside the small buffer); as you see (red arrows), the line at the bottom has an additional vertex in the middle. The line in the middle almost touches the buffer's boundary. So both these lines are not perfectly straight:*

[image]

---

*This works to evaluate the line as a whole. To identify straight vs. curved sub-sections of longer linestrings, see [Sorting out curved and straight lines in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397855/sorting-out-curved-and-straight-lines-in-qgis/397907#397907)*.