# Quantizing the value of straightness or waviness of line segment in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, linestring

Is there a tool in QGIS that can calculate how smooth or zigzagy a line is in the XY plane (not Z profile) between two points, or how can I quantize this value so that I can compare the straightness or waviness of line segments?

Comment: Please find some details in this thread : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446326/is-the-linestring-straight

Answer (score 10):

You can use QGIS expression with the [`sinuosity()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#sinuosity) function:

```
sinuosity($geometry)
```

> Returns the sinuosity of a curve, which is the ratio of the curve
> length to the straight (2D) distance between its endpoints.

For a more sophisticated approach, including the curvature of parts of a line, see [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397907/88814).

*several lines labeled with the expression `sinuosity ($geometry)`:*

[image]