# How to determine apex / angular points in QGIS-3

Tags: qgis-3, angles, azimuth, curve, apex

How could I find the apices / angular / turning points of a linestring in QGIS3? The logic behind that should be to determine consecutive segments with same direction (always right or always left), where direction doesn't change, and then determine the "highpoints" or "curve apices" of these sections. I hope that I've got the vacabulary right to describe the problem.

[image: curve mid points]

Addendum 1:

That's what I've achieved so far, in finding "turning points", or switches in direction: With the expression builder I've iterated over the nodes of the lines and calculated the angles between consecutive line segments. The angles in the resulting array (stringified) are the change of direction, heading from one segment to the other. A change of sign, denotes a change in direction..

```
array_to_string(
    with_variable('pts', nodes_to_points($geometry),
         array_foreach(generate_series(1,num_points(@pts)-2),
            with_variable('dgr',
                degrees(
                        azimuth(geometry_n(@pts,@element+1), geometry_n(@pts,@element+2)) -
                        azimuth(geometry_n(@pts,@element), geometry_n(@pts,@element+1))
                        
                ) ,
                round(if(@dgr >= 180, @dgr - 360, if(@dgr <= -180, @dgr + 360, @dgr)),0)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Addendum 2:
This worked for getting the "turning points":
(I've added those points, first as virtual text field with unlimited length, and then, for rendering, with the geometry generator and `geom_from_wkt()`

```
geom_to_wkt(
    collect_geometries(
        array_foreach(
            array_filter( 
                with_variable('my_arr', 
                    with_variable('pts', nodes_to_points($geometry),
                         array_foreach(generate_series(1,num_points(@pts)-2),
                            with_variable('dgr',
                                degrees(
                                        azimuth(geometry_n(@pts,@element), geometry_n(@pts,@element+1)) -
                                        azimuth(geometry_n(@pts,@element+1), geometry_n(@pts,@element+2))
                                        
                                ), if(@dgr >= 180, @dgr - 360, if(@dgr <= -180, @dgr + 360, @dgr))>0
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    array_foreach(generate_series(0, array_length(@my_arr)-2), 
                        if(@my_arr[@element]!=@my_arr[@element+1], @element, 0)
                    )
                ), @element > 0
            ), 
            geometries_to_array(nodes_to_points($geometry))[@element+2]
        )
    )
)
```

[image: Turning points]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TomBrennan I've supplemented the OP.

Comment: What about simplify tool in processing toolbox? Setting a reasonable tolerance for Douglas-Peucker method can solve it.

Comment: ..@Zoltan I hoped for a more generic solution.

Comment: Looks like you are heading in the right direction with your expression. However, be aware that your original line looks like it's made of many vertices. The angle between subsequent vertices is likely to be small, even for a fairly sharp bend. You will need to perhaps use a rolling window approach where you look at the total heading change over several vertices.

Comment: @Matt, I think there is another way: (1) find the turning points (as in addendum 2), then somehow find the "apex" or "highpoint" for each of these "arc-segments" (stretches between 2 turning points)...  Sorry, I'm lacking the mathematical terms for this..

Comment: Essentially this is the same process as differentiation in maths, where each time the slope (first derivative) is 0 there is an "apex". The complexity of your particular problem is due to the fact that the linestrings can be oriented in any direction - not just y = f(x), and can change that orientation even within a single linestring. I think that's going to make a general solution hard.

Comment: One possible approach given that you have identified the turning points would be to fit a cubic curve to each segment (not sure how in QGIS, but there may be plugins), find the sharpest turn in that curve (using differentiation), and finally the closest point on your original segment to that turn. But it probably depends on the ultimate purpose of this analysis.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397907/88814

Comment: I think the solution is to find a way to determine the indices of the array values with abs. max angles within the subsets with same sign (consecutive left and right hand turns). An array with angle change values would look like this [10,17,27,88,20,12,0,-7,-12,-20,-23,-27,-32,-20,-19,-12,-7,-3,6,34,56,41,32,21]. The abs. max for first part (pos. sign, which are right hand bends) would be 88 degrees = sharpest bend, and the index is 4,  the second abs. max (in the following series of left hand bends, with neg. sign) would be 32, with index 13, and so on.. With the indices I'd get the nodes..