# Defining outbound and return directions of GPS points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, gps, direction, trajectory

In QGIS, I have a layer of points corresponding to the positions of my vehicles every 2 seconds. So, my layer contains the following information:

- XY coordinates
- Vehicle number
- GPS heading
- Timestamp
- Speed of the vehicule

I would like to know if it is possible in QGIS to define the outbound and return directions based on GPS heading.

By assigning the "GPS_HEADING" field to the rotation parameter of my points' symbology, I can clearly see the direction of my points. However, I would like this information to be included in my attributes (1 for outbound and 2 for return).

I have already tried using the "Separate points by direction" tool from SAGA, but the separation is not done correctly; there are errors as shown in the following figure (there are points going in the same direction that are supposed to have the same color).

I am using QGIS version 3.34.0.

[image]

Comment: Are you defining outbound and return journeys purely by the heading between points? In which case you can just use a threshold: `0 < heading < 20 = outbound`. Otherwise, you need to define the point at which the outbound journey becomes the return journey. That could be a geographic location, an amount of time, or the point in the route where the car double backs on itself, in which case, [this answer may help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397907/128665)

Comment: Is this just a single straight road?